# fill up excel spreadsheet with address given(first line + postcode) UK

Tags: vb.net, excel, spreadsheet

[image]I would like to know if there is way in excel I can fill up the addresses by having the first line of the address and postcode.

Example I have Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Postcode.

I have Address1, + postcode but not always have the other fields, such as town, county.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ok how can this be done? I have address 1 such as 10 XXXXXXXX , post code AB1 1BH? I want fill up town and county

Comment: You'll need to get a database or some list of all post codes, counties, etc. that you want to match with.  Then just use a vlookup or index/match formula to fill in the empty blanks.  Please read the page I linked to, it outlines how to ask a good question. Please try what I and Yaegz have said (get a db and do some kind of lookup to fill in the spots). Then let us know what you've tried, and how it is/is not working.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you for your reply. yes its is good idea to do that I have spreadsheet working, its is difficult to get accurate free db with postcode and count, town info. I was thinking if I can connect excel to API, as I have API that does this already, but I am not expert in excel

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us very much information to go on.  But you can accomplish this with something like the below.  If you have an actual example I can give you a better formula.

[image]

Comment: Please see picture above on the top. So I have postcode and firstline of the address. So is there any api or vb code that can run and fill up address 2 with Northampton and Address3 with Northamptonshire

Comment: Oh, in that case you are going to have to find a table that has UK post codes and their associated town and county.  Then I would just do a Vlookup or index/match to fill in the town and county.

Answer (score 0):

https://blogs.office.com/2013/03/21/use-webservice-functions-to-automatically-update-excel-2013-spreadsheets-with-online-data/

I used =WEbservice() function that we have on excel 2013 this to call my api.

Works perfectly.

Thanks